# Creating a Table in SQL with constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I am trying to create a table.  I am unable to compile it successfully.  Could someone please point me in the right direction

Here is my code:

```
 CREATE TABLE TESTING_TODAY
 (
 EMP_NUM NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL, 
 RTG_CODE CHAR(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
 EARNED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT PK_TESTING_TODAY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
   [EMP_NUM] ASC,
   [RTG_CODE] ASC
 )
 );
 COMMIT;
```

Comment: If you're "unable to compile it", presumably you're getting some sort of error.  It would be awfully helpful to specify that error.  You haven't told us what database you're connected to.  You've tagged this for SQL Developer which would imply an Oracle database but the SQL you've posted definitely isn't Oracle DDL.

Comment: @Justin CaveI am using Oracle SQL Developer as I tagged it.   The error is "Error at Command Line : 6 Column : 12
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02250: missing or invalid constraint name
02250. 00000 -  "missing or invalid constraint name"
*Cause:    The constraint name is missing or invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid identifier name for the constraint name."

Comment: In future, read the error message. (i.e. learn to fish, you'll feed yourself for a lifetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CLUSTERED` is invalid in Oracle and `[`,`]` are invalid in SQL identifiers:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING_TODAY
(
   EMP_NUM NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL, 
   RTG_CODE CHAR(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
   EARNED_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PK_TESTING_TODAY PRIMARY KEY (EMP_NUM,RTG_CODE)
);
COMMIT;
```

- More details about valid SQL identifiers:
  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223
- Full documentation for the `CREATE TABLE` statement:
  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402

Comment: Thank you.  I was pointed in the wrong direction earlier by a friend.  Thanks for the clarification and good articles.